# Call method from view in reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

I'm using react redux to make a login page and home.

After I did the authentication on the server and called the reducer, I do not know how I can pass to view that I am authenticated and to transfer to the home.
Being that in my Reducer I am already passing a message when the user and password are invalid.

LoginService.js

```
 export default class LoginService {
    static realizaLogin(login, senha) {
        return dispatch => {
            dispatch(isLoading(true));
            axios.post('account/login', { Login: login, Senha: senha })
                .then(res => {
                    var result = res.data;

                    if (result.IsValid) {
                        dispatch(acessoValido(result.Data));
                    } else {
                        dispatch(acessoInvalido(result.Errors[0].Message));
                    }

                    dispatch(isLoading(false));
                }).catch(error => {
                    dispatch(acessoInvalido(error.message));
                    dispatch(isLoading(false));
                });

        }
    }
}
```

LoginReducer.js

```
 export function loginReducer(state = '', action) {

    if (action.type === 'ACESSAR') {
        return action.usuario;
    } else if (action.type === 'ACESSO-INVALIDO') {
        return { mensagemLoginInvalido: action.mensagemLoginInvalido };
    }
    return state;
}
```

LoginPage.js

```
class LoginPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(this.props);

  }

  realizaLogin(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.realizaLogin(this.usuario.value, this.senha.value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Loading store={this.props.store} />
        <div className="login bg app flex-row align-items-center">
          <Container className="container">
            <Row className="justify-content-center">
              <img src={require('./../../assets/img/brand/logo.png')} alt="Logo do GateClinic" width="300px" height="200px" />
            </Row>
            <Row className="justify-content-center">
              <Col md="6">
                <Card className="p-4">
                  <CardBody>
                    <Form onSubmit={this.realizaLogin.bind(this)}>
                      <InputGroup className="mb-3">
                        <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
                          <InputGroupText>
                            <FontAwesomeIcon icon="building" />
                          </InputGroupText>
                        </InputGroupAddon>
                        <Input type="text" placeholder="Empresa" id="empresa" />
                      </InputGroup>
                      <InputGroup className="mb-3">
                        <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
                          <InputGroupText>
                            <FontAwesomeIcon icon="user" />
                          </InputGroupText>
                        </InputGroupAddon>
                        <Input type="text" placeholder="Usuário" id="usuario" innerRef={input => this.usuario = input} />
                      </InputGroup>
                      <InputGroup className="mb-4">
                        <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
                          <InputGroupText>
                            <FontAwesomeIcon icon="lock" />
                          </InputGroupText>
                        </InputGroupAddon>
                        <Input type="password" placeholder="Senha" id="senha" innerRef={input => this.senha = input} />
                        <FormFeedback className={`${(this.props.mensagemLoginInvalido && this.props.mensagemLoginInvalido !== '' ? 'display-block' : '')} text-align-center`}>
                          {this.props.mensagemLoginInvalido}
                        </FormFeedback>
                      </InputGroup>
                      <Row>
                        <Col xs="6">
                          <Button color="primary" className="px-4" type="submit" >Acessar</Button>
                        </Col>
                        <Col xs="6" className="text-right">
                          <Button color="link" className="px-0">Esqueci minha senha?</Button>
                        </Col>
                      </Row>

                    </Form>
                  </CardBody>
                </Card>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Container>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { mensagemLoginInvalido: state.loginReducer.mensagemLoginInvalido }
};
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    realizaLogin: (usuario, senha) => {
      dispatch(LoginService.realizaLogin(usuario, senha));
    }
  }
}

const LoginPageContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginPage);

export default withRouter(LoginPageContainer);
```

Comment: ideally, you should put the state of your action in store. and use store data in your component to proceed with your logic. if you add or call a method from view in reducer that would be an anti pattern for the whole flux architecture.

Comment: do you can show me a example? like my case?

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your login api reponse in store. and use that in your component. 
example:

```
const defaultState = {
  loading:false, // you can take advantage of this to show a loader
  loginSuccess:false,
  userData={}
  error:null
}
export function loginReducer(state = defaultState, action) {

    if (action.type === 'ACESSAR') {
        return {...state,loginSuccess:true,userData:action.payload}
    } else if (action.type === 'ACESSO-INVALIDO') {
        return {...state,loginSuccess:false,userData={},error:action.payload}
    }
    return state;
   }
```

in your component.

```
class LoginPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props); 
  }

 componentWillRecieveProps(nextProps){
  if(nextProps.loginSuccess){
    // redirect to home page.
  }
  if (nextProps.error) {
    // do something
  }
 }

  render() {
    return (
      ...
      ... your view
      ...
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { 
    loading:state.loading
    loginSuccess:state.loginSuccess,
    userData=state.userData
    error:state.error
  }
};
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    realizaLogin: (usuario, senha) => {
      dispatch(LoginService.realizaLogin(usuario, senha));
    }
  }
}

const LoginPageContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginPage);

export default withRouter(LoginPageContainer);
```

Comment: that's great. to make your app even better. you can use some middleware with redux to make api calls. like `redux-thunk` or `redux-sagas`. also you can upvote the answer if you like :D